# Getting Unknown flag: -v when i run protoc -version in my ubuntu

Tags: protocol-buffers, ubuntu-14.04

I'm getting the following message when i run protoc -version in my ubuntu terminal.

Unknown flag: -v

Earlier to this, I had got the following error when I ran protoc -version. I found a solution through google and ran "sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib". After running that, I'm getting the Unknown flag message as mentioned above. Can anyone help me to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

protoc: error while loading shared libraries: libprotoc.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Did you compile protoc yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long flags require two dashes. Try:

```
protoc --version
```

(Common Unix convention says that if you write `-abc` (with one dash), it means the same thing as `-a -b -c`, which is why you get the error saying that there is no flag `-v`. Admittedly, there are a lot of Unix programs that don't follow this rule, but `protoc` does follow it.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I would have voted up if I'm eligible. sorry my account has low reputation score. But sincere thanks again :)